# Is there an equation for the relationship between illuminance and the resistance of a light dependent resistor?

Tags: resistance, ldr

All I've seen on this is:

> R = A.E<sup>a</sup>.
>
> where E – illumination (lux),
> R – resistance (ohms) and
> A, a – constants.
>
> The value of ‘a’ depends on the CdS used and on the manufacturing process. Values usually range between 0.7 and 0.9".

But I'm not sure how to use this. Does anyone know of anything?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet or a part number? If I were a manufacturer, I'd probably come up with curves for different wavelengths/intensities and stick them on a datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

As @yhyrcanus said, I would refer to the [manufacturer datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Photonic%20Detetectors%20Inc%20PDFs/PDV-P8104.pdf).

This datasheet shows the sensitivity of the photodiode as 8 ohm/lux. There's the slope of your equation.

This [datasheet from Adafruit](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/photocells.pdf) gives a little info on photoresistors and also shows the R vs lux graph on page 5.

According to the Adafruit datasheet, photoresistors can vary greatly from the same batch, ±50% or more. So you may want to characterize each photoresistor individually if you need a specific sensitivity.